# Determining corrupt JPEG images through exception handling

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, exception, jpeg

I'm loading .jpg files residing in a folder to the workspace and perform some operations on them later. However, on some files, I get a warning about Corrupt JPEG files. I do not need to do an inspection on those files by eye, however, they should be excluded from the process. Hence, I need to be able to determine if a given image is corrupt in the aforementioned way, or not.

Although imread throws out such warning, it does not provide a flag. I want to use a function, similar to this fashion.

Here is the sample code

```
path=dir('*.jpg');

for i=1:length(dir)

image=imread(dir(i,1).name);
flag=iscorrupt(MException.last);

if (not(flag))
    ...
end
end

function out=iscorrupt(exception)
exception.message, out=isempty(strfind(exception.message,'corrupt'));
```

However, this partial code won't fulfill the purpose, as it depends on the last exception. Thus, after a corrupt warning is thrown, it will always set True flag. I'd like to know, if it possible to capture the required knowledge using the above approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up to this. Leaving here for future references.

```
flag=iscorrupt(lastwarn);

...


function out=iscorrupt(exception)
out=not(isempty(strfind(lower(exception),'corrupt')));
warning('Image is ignored')
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would encapsulate your `imread` in a `try/catch` idiom.  That way every time an exception is thrown, you can simply continue in the loop without even bothering to read from the corrupt image.  Also there are some slight typos when you are calling `dir` and the way you are accessing the actual names for each of the files.  I'll fix that for you though.

Try something like this:

```
path = dir('*.jpg');

for i = 1 : length(path)
    try 
        im = imread(path(i).name);
        %//Continue your code here
        %...
    catch ME %//Skip to next iteration if corrupt message occurs for image i
        if (~isempty(strfind(ME.message,'corrupt')))
             continue;
        end
    end
 end
```

Aside:  I'm not sure if this will work, but looking at the MATLAB documentation, you can reset the most recent uncaught exception by doing `MException.last('reset');`.  If you did this in each iteration of your loop, would this also solve your problem?

Comment: It definitely would. Sorry for a bad question (alien to the exceptions). Thanks for a detailed response.

Comment: Definitely **not** a bad question at all!  You've got a pretty good system for throwing out images that you shouldn't bother to look at.  How `try/catch` works is that within the `try` statement, you put in code that **may** throw an exception.  As soon as anything within the `try` statement causes an exception, the code will immediately jump over to the `catch` block where you can handle the exception.  `ME` will contain whatever exception was thrown within the `try` block. It's similar to what you see in any object-oriented programming language (C++, Java, Python). Hope this helped you!